# google signin with firebase stopped working

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

ive been working on this project for a while and it was working well but now when  the google signin button is pressed the dialog to choose account appears and when  the account is selected  it doesn't let me in the App and still shows the login screen.Flutter doctor has no issues. Flutter sdk and Pub is up to date

everything is fine expect now i noticed the Buildcontext in Navigator.push apppears pink in color.

```
 Navigator.push(context/*this context appears in pink color*/
, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccount()));
```

I've pasted the log below:

```
 Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Waiting for SM G973U to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58142/YwXVHgNoPX4=/ws
Syncing files to device SM G973U...
I/flutter (18599): Error signing in: PlatformException(sign_in_required, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: 4: , null)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(I)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(ILjava/lang/String;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->size()I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->get(I)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->getName(I)Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
E/FlutterFcmService(18599): Fatal: failed to find callback
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
W/ActivityThread(18599): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@ab7575
I/MultiWindowDecorSupport(18599): updateCaptionType >> DecorView@ed33029[], isFloating: false, isApplication: true, hasWindowDecorCaption: false, hasWindowControllerCallback: true
D/MultiWindowDecorSupport(18599): setCaptionType = 0, DecorView = DecorView@ed33029[]
D/ViewRootImpl@ef08686[SignInHubActivity](18599): setView = com.android.internal.policy.DecorView@ed33029 TM=true MM=false
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager(18599): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@72437a8[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(18599): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/ViewRootImpl@ef08686[SignInHubActivity](18599): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1440,3040) new=(0,0,1440,2827) req=(1440,3040)0 dur=8 res=0x7 s={true 503781363712} ch=true
D/OpenGLRenderer(18599): createReliableSurface : 0x74b0f3f880(0x754bb59000)
D/OpenGLRenderer(18599): makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x74b0c99700 -> 0x74597f7000
D/ViewRootImpl@ef08686[SignInHubActivity](18599): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager(18599): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ed33029[SignInHubActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(18599): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputMethodManager(18599): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ed33029[SignInHubActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(18599): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager(18599): Starting input: tba=com.marcwaltonchel.fashow ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager(18599): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager(18599): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport(18599): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=94
D/ViewRootImpl@ef08686[SignInHubActivity](18599): MSG_RESIZED: frame=(0,0,1440,2827) ci=(0,150,0,0) vi=(0,150,0,0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl@ef08686[SignInHubActivity](18599): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager(18599): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ed33029[SignInHubActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(18599): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputTransport(18599): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=107
D/ViewRootImpl@ef08686[SignInHubActivity](18599): stopped(false) old=false
D/ViewRootImpl@ef08686[SignInHubActivity](18599): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager(18599): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ed33029[SignInHubActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(18599): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputMethodManager(18599): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ed33029[SignInHubActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(18599): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager(18599): Starting input: tba=com.marcwaltonchel.fashow ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager(18599): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager(18599): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): stopped(false) old=false
D/OpenGLRenderer(18599): makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x74597f7000 -> 0x0
D/OpenGLRenderer(18599): destroyEglSurface : 0x74597f7000
D/OpenGLRenderer(18599): ~ReliableSurface : 0x74b0f3f880
D/ViewRootImpl@ef08686[SignInHubActivity](18599): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1440,2827) new=(0,0,1440,2827) req=(1440,2827)8 dur=3 res=0x5 s={false 0} ch=true
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager(18599): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@72437a8[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(18599): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputMethodManager(18599): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@72437a8[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(18599): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager(18599): Starting input: tba=com.marcwaltonchel.fashow ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager(18599): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager(18599): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport(18599): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=121
D/ViewRootImpl@ef08686[SignInHubActivity](18599): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager(18599): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ed33029[SignInHubActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(18599): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/ViewRootImpl@ef08686[SignInHubActivity](18599): stopped(true) old=false
D/ViewRootImpl@ef08686[SignInHubActivity](18599): dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport(18599): Input channel destroyed: '74684d1', fd=103
D/ConnectivityManager(18599): requestNetwork; CallingUid : 10719, CallingPid : 18599
W/DynamiteModule(18599): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(18599): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(18599): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/ltonchel.fasho(18599): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/ltonchel.fasho(18599): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
V/NativeCrypto(18599): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native methods...
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayBaseOffset(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->copyMemory(JJJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->objectFieldOffset(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getByte(J)B (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getByte(Ljava/lang/Object;J)B (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putByte(JB)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putByte(Ljava/lang/Object;JB)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(18599): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/ProviderInstaller(18599): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
D/ConnectivityManager(18599): requestNetwork; CallingUid : 10719, CallingPid : 18599
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden field Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->descriptor:I (greylist, JNI, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/Firestore(18599): (21.3.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(users/110432591502424202527) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
E/flutter (18599): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error performing get, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null)
E/flutter (18599): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:570:7)
E/flutter (18599): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:159:18)
E/flutter (18599): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18599): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:12)
E/flutter (18599): #3      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:359:48)
E/flutter (18599): #4      MethodChannelDocumentReference.get (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_reference.dart:56:46)
E/flutter (18599): #5      DocumentReference.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_reference.dart:69:47)
E/flutter (18599): #6      _HomePageState.createUserInFirestore (package:fashow/HomePage.dart:127:61)
E/flutter (18599): #7      _HomePageState.handleSignIn (package:fashow/HomePage.dart:72:13)
E/flutter (18599): #8      _HomePageState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:fashow/HomePage.dart:58:7)
E/flutter (18599): #9      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter (18599): #10     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (18599): #11     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (18599): #12     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)
E/flutter (18599): #13     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:611:14)
E/flutter (18599): #14     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:730:11)
E/flutter (18599): #15     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:687:7)
E/flutter (18599): #16     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
E/flutter (18599): #17     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (18599): #18     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter (18599): #19     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter (18599): #20     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter (18599): #21     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (18599): #22     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter (18599): #23     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter (18599): #24     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter (18599): #25     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
E/flutter (18599): 
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager(18599): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@72437a8[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(18599): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager(18599): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@72437a8[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(18599): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/SurfaceView(18599): onWindowVisibilityChanged(8) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827} of ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity]
D/SurfaceView(18599): surfaceDestroyed callback.size 1 #2 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827}
D/SurfaceView(18599): remove() io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827} Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.marcwaltonchel.fashow/com.fashow.fashow.MainActivity@31245bb@0)/@0xc38bc9b
D/OpenGLRenderer(18599): destroyEglSurface : 0x74b0c99700
D/OpenGLRenderer(18599): ~ReliableSurface : 0x74b0d66500
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1440,2827) new=(0,0,1440,2827) req=(1440,2827)8 dur=4 res=0x5 s={false 0} ch=true
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager(18599): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@72437a8[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(18599): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): stopped(true) old=false
D/SurfaceView(18599): windowStopped(true) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827} of ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity]
D/InputTransport(18599): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=117
D/SurfaceView(18599): onWindowVisibilityChanged(4) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827} of ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity]
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1440,2827) new=(0,0,1440,2827) req=(1440,2827)4 dur=7 res=0x1 s={false 0} ch=false
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): stopped(false) old=true
D/SurfaceView(18599): windowStopped(false) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827} of ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity]
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): stopped(false) old=false
D/SurfaceView(18599): onWindowVisibilityChanged(0) true io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827} of ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity]
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1440,2827) new=(0,0,1440,2827) req=(1440,2827)0 dur=12 res=0x7 s={true 499726008320} ch=true
D/OpenGLRenderer(18599): createReliableSurface : 0x74b0d66500(0x7459fdc000)
D/SurfaceView(18599): surfaceCreated 1 #8 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827}
D/SurfaceView(18599): surfaceChanged (1440,2827) 1 #8 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827}
D/OpenGLRenderer(18599): makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x0 -> 0x74b0c99480
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager(18599): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@72437a8[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(18599): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputMethodManager(18599): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@72437a8[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(18599): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager(18599): Starting input: tba=com.marcwaltonchel.fashow ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager(18599): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager(18599): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/SurfaceView(18599): onWindowVisibilityChanged(8) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827} of ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity]
D/SurfaceView(18599): surfaceDestroyed callback.size 1 #2 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827}
D/SurfaceView(18599): remove() io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827} Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.marcwaltonchel.fashow/com.fashow.fashow.MainActivity@31245bb@1)/@0xe0a9d4e
D/OpenGLRenderer(18599): makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x74b0c99480 -> 0x0
D/OpenGLRenderer(18599): destroyEglSurface : 0x74b0c99480
D/OpenGLRenderer(18599): ~ReliableSurface : 0x74b0d66500
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1440,2827) new=(0,0,1440,2827) req=(1440,2827)8 dur=6 res=0x5 s={false 0} ch=true
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): stopped(true) old=false
D/SurfaceView(18599): windowStopped(true) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827} of ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity]
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager(18599): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@72437a8[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(18599): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputTransport(18599): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=97
D/SurfaceView(18599): onWindowVisibilityChanged(4) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827} of ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity]
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1440,2827) new=(0,0,1440,2827) req=(1440,2827)4 dur=22 res=0x1 s={false 0} ch=false
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): stopped(false) old=true
D/SurfaceView(18599): windowStopped(false) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827} of ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity]
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): stopped(false) old=false
D/SurfaceView(18599): onWindowVisibilityChanged(0) true io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827} of ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity]
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1440,2827) new=(0,0,1440,2827) req=(1440,2827)0 dur=15 res=0x7 s={true 503781154816} ch=true
D/OpenGLRenderer(18599): createReliableSurface : 0x74b0d66500(0x754bb26000)
D/SurfaceView(18599): surfaceCreated 1 #8 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827}
D/SurfaceView(18599): surfaceChanged (1440,2827) 1 #8 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{31245bb V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2827}
D/OpenGLRenderer(18599): makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x0 -> 0x74b0c99700
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager(18599): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@72437a8[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(18599): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputMethodManager(18599): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@72437a8[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(18599): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager(18599): Starting input: tba=com.marcwaltonchel.fashow ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager(18599): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager(18599): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0bf03e[MainActivity](18599): ViewPostIme pointer 1
V/NativeCrypto(18599): Write error: ssl=0x7459dc7988: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
V/NativeCrypto(18599): SSL shutdown failed: ssl=0x7459dc7988: I/O error during system call, Success
W/ltonchel.fasho(18599): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
```

Comment: This might help you: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27599#issuecomment-463739569

Comment: check SHA-1 key. and update same in firebase console

Comment: i updated SHA - 1 key on firebase console and updated json too. still not working

Comment: That doesn't really sound like a google sing in issue, but rather handling the result whenever the user signs in using google. Are you sure you are *navigating* the user to the correct widget?

Comment: everything is fine expect now i noticed the Buildcontext in  Navigator.push apppears pink in color.Navigator.push(context(appears in pink color) , MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccount()));